# What are some good workarounds for dart's lack of static typing semantics?

Tags: dart

I'm coming from C#/F#/Haskell so I'm trying to come up with solutions to programming problems I'm used to solving with types.

1. class A where T : new() in C#, this is mainly so I can do new T() somewhere. This creates a malformed type error in Dart. Is there a reasonably idiomatic way to solve this? Perhaps with factories?
2. I did some experiments with mixins, in the case of name conflicts for inherited mixin members, the last mixin wins. So for the following:
   abstract class mixA { void foo(); }
   abstract class mixB { void foo(); }
   class C extends Object with mixA, mixB {}
   new C().foo();

this would end up calling mixB.foo() whereas
class C extends Object with mixB, mixA {}
would end up calling mixA.foo()
Is there anyway to access the members of the hidden mixins?

Suppose I mix 2 mixins with a field of the same name. Does the subclass instance have 2 fields at runtime (just 1 is inaccessible) or is the object like a dictionary and there is only 1 slot for each name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 is not possible. You can't call `new` on a generic type (or variable for that matter). The most common workaround is to create a closure that allocates the object instead.

The answers for 2 fall out of the fact that Mixins can be seen as super-classes: `A extends Object with B, C` is basically equivalent to:

```
class B' extends Object { <copy over code inside B> }
class C' extends B' { <copy over code inside C> }
class D extends C' { ... }
```

With this in mind:

- no. there is no way to access hidden super elements.
- yes. you would end up with multiple fields.

Small note: the `<copy over code inside X>` part is not completely correct since that would change the library-scope. Code from mixin B is conceptually in the library the mixin is declared in.