# Is it possible to instantiate a class from a dynamic var?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I have many objects of the same base type. I want to build a generic function to create them. Code sample :

```dart
class Grid extends Display { ....
class Start extends Display { ....

class MainClass {
  Grid grid;
  Start start;
  ....
}
```

in a MainClass method, instead of this :

```dart
start = new Start();
start.load(PATH);

grid = new Grid();
grid.load(PATH);

....
```

I would like to do something like this :

```dart
void _newDisplay(dynamicType, Display display) {
  display = new dynamicType();
  display.load(PATH);        
}

_newDisplay(Start, start);
_newDisplay(Grid, grid);

....
```

I read http://www.dartlang.org/articles/optional-types/ but did not find exactly what I wanted.

I also found [Instantiate a class from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242712/instantiate-a-class-from-a-string/) but there is a comment saying : "Note: this might not work when compiled to JavaScript. The dart2js compiler doesn't yet fully support mirrors.".  Is this "mirror" solution the only one available to make dynamic instantiation ?

Comment: re: mirrors and dart2js. It is our intention to support mirrors with dart2js, and we're working on it, but it's not 100% yet. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dart doesn't support a direct way to do this. Usually we work around this by providing a closure that instantiates the type for us:

```dart
void _newDisplay(dynamicType, Display display) {
  display = dynamicType();
  display.load(PATH);        
}

_newDisplay(() => Start(), start);
_newDisplay(() => Grid(), grid);
```

Also see [What are some good workarounds for dart's lack of static typing semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334791/what-are-some-good-workarounds-for-darts-lack-of-static-typing-semantics/16348380#16348380)